# None type object has no attribute delete()

Tags: django

## getting error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'

```
class LogoutViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def (self,request):
        user_token=request.auth
        refresh_token=RefreshToken.objects.filter(access_token=user_token)
        refresh_token.delete()
        user_token.delete()
        return Response({'done':True})
```

Comment: check the value of "refresh_token" and "user_token".

Comment: what is `def (...)` ? what method are you overriding?

Answer (score 0):

Since request.auth is not a QuerySet you cannot use `delete()` method on it.

```
class LogoutViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

def (self,request):
    user_token=request.auth
    refresh_token=RefreshToken.objects.filter(access_token=user_token)
    refresh_token.delete()
    user_token = None
    return Response({'done':True})
```

Answer (score 0):

class LogoutViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

```
def list(self,request):
    try:
        user_token=request.auth
        print('TOKEN',request.auth)
        refresh_token=RefreshToken.objects.filter(access_token=user_token)
        refresh_token.delete()
        user_token.delete()
        return Response({'done':True}) 
    except Exception as error:
        return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False},
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

## then follo steps

1:in postman select GET 
2:unser Header type (i)=Key=Authorization
               type (ii)=Value=Bearer CMEIe8hv8eMYvAcLyTGpAlXMpUb0Qz(token)